# Get audio rtp packet G729

Tags: c#, rtp

I'm using sharppcap and PacketDotNet to filter RTP ​​packets from my computer. Now I'm trying to retrieve the audio RTP packet with g729 codec. I am using the following code, but the audio is not complete.

```
public static byte[] ReturnAudio(UdpPacket PacketUdp)
    {

        byte[] payload = { };

        int cont= 0;

        for (int i = 20; i <= PacketUdp.Bytes.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            Array.Resize(ref payload, cont + 1);

            payload[cont] = PacketUdp.Bytes[i];

            cont += 1;
        }


        return payload;

    }
```

Real Call:

> U1:
>   ----Hi---------two---------four--------six-----------eitgh---------ten--
>
> U2:
>   Hi------One--------three--------five-------seven---------nine----

My recorde file:

> U1: ----Hi-------two-------four------six--------eitgh------ten
>
> U2: Hi---One------three----five----seven---nine-----

Comment: This code is not enough to reproduce the issue or answer the question. Please show that you have tried to debug this issue: what _is_ the problem and what solution are you asking for? If the problem is that the code shown is too slow in processing, try using `Buffer.BlockCopy` instead of resizing an array N-20 times for a packet of size N.

Comment: The method receives an RTP packet and looks the part of audio contained in the RTP packet and copies it into a buffer. This buffer is written to a file. Below is the link as is. In the first instance how the connection occurs in the second as it gets when it is written to the file, see who is outside synchronous running.

Comment: I understand what the code does. I'm just curious what exactly you're asking. We can't analyze the problem from the code shown, apart from the remark I made in my previous comment. Are you sure you receive all packets and you write all data you should write? How do you compare the output? How do you determine there is data missing? What _exactly_ are you missing, entire or partial packets?

Comment: When I go to record the data from the buffer to a file recording is no "timing". Implying that it is "missing samples silence" in the file. :)

Comment: I don't know this protocol and I don't know what you're trying to say in your comment. Is it possible that you don't receive packets if the protocol thinks there is no sound, where you should actually write "silence packets" instead of nothing?

Comment: Maybe I have not expressed myself correctly. What is happening is the following: When you receive the RTP packet payload I try to copy the audio part into the buffer when I'll listen to the recording it is not timing. When you open the file from the audio input and audio output to realize the amount of sample injected into the silence file is smaller than the actual, so the lack of synchronization. There is an audio supression for transmitting data supression that when there is silence packets are not sent to non occupied bandwidth.

Comment: It Looks like the Sender has Voice Activity Detection enabled and is sending silence packets/comfort noise Generation packets instead of G.729 packets. You'll Need to look at a Network trace to check that.